# Adding numbers across multiple fields wont add decimals

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate the values of multiple fields and place the total in another box.  It works with whole numbers but for some reason won't add 7.25 or 7.50 for example.

I tried changing my `tot += parseInt(arr[i].value).toFixed(2);` but that didn't work.  Any help is appreciated.

```js
        function findTotal(){
            var arr = document.getElementsByName('monday');
            var tot=0;
            for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
                    tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
            }
            document.getElementById('totalHours').value = tot;
        }
```

```html
        Monday : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="monday" id="monday1"/><br>
        Monday : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="monday" id="monday2"/><br>
        Monday : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="monday" id="monday3"/><br>
        Monday : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="monday" id="monday4"/><br>
        Monday : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="monday" id="monday5"/><br>
        Monday : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="monday" id="monday6"/><br>
        
        <br><br>
        Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="totalHours"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parseInt` will remove the decimal part
you should use `parseFloat`

Comment: Ah, so simple. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

User parseFloat() instead of parseInt(),

```
function findTotal(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('monday');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseFloat(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('totalHours').value = tot;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tot += Number(Number(arr[i].value).toFixed(2))
```